# Bombing the Ballot - How can I disarm the bomb?

Tags: another-case-solved

In chapter 4, the case "Bombing the Ballot", I am truly stuck as I am unable to disarm the bomb. I have replayed it 3 times, each time with a different wire cut. But it always blows up. I can find no hint or clue anywhere in the game.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I found a room near the center top of the screen where the bomb was made! Look at the leftover pieces in the center desk for a clue.

Comment: Just like in Suspicious Syrup, the room just before contains the alarm box with the right wire. So this is the best possible answer!

Answer (score 0):

I used a tool for safely removing the alarm wires, which got me down to two of them. In my game, the yellow wire was the right one.